# append ajax response on popup window using jquery-mobile

Tags: php, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a application . in that i want to append ajax response on 
    popup window using jquery mobile . so how to append it . i am posting some
    few   code . i want to append response on *d2 id* that id is of  tag.
   **My ajax code**

```
  $("#b1").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"http://localhost/register.php",
    data: $("#frm").serialize(),
    success:function(response)

        {

        $("#d2").html(response);


         },
         error:function(response)
         {
                     }
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$("#d2").html(response.responseText);
```

see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_ajax_response.htm